# I cannot display custom post on variable products. Any idea how to fix it?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I add few custom field on the woocommerce product. I used the code below to display the custom field on the Woocommerce process : cart; check out; order and email. But I can't make them appear on variable product process. It works perfectly on single product. Can anyone help me with to fix my code? Thanks a lot :)

```
/**
 Display info
 **/

// Admin: Add custom field
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'vp_add_pp_info' );
function vp_add_pp_info(){

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_venue',
        'label'       => __('Venue', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Venue here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __('This field is for the Venue of the product.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_date',
        'label'       => __('Date', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Date here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __('This field is for the Date of the product.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_time',
        'label'       => __('Time', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter Time here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __('This field is for the time of the product.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
}

// Admin: Save custom field value for simple product inventory options
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'vp_product_save_pp_info', 10, 1 );
function vp_product_save_pp_info( $product ){
    if( isset($_POST['_venue']) )
        $product->update_meta_data( '_venue', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_venue']) );

    if( isset($_POST['_date']) )
        $product->update_meta_data( '_date', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_date']) );

    if( isset($_POST['_time']) )
        $product->update_meta_data( '_time', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_time']) );
}




// Frontend: Display PP Info on product
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'vp_product_display_pp_info' );
function vp_product_display_pp_info() {
    global $product;

    if( $value = $product->get_meta( '_venue' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="vp-ccode-wrapper"><strong>' . __("Venue info", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</div>';
    }
    if( $value = $product->get_meta( '_date' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="vp-ccode-wrapper"><strong>' . __("Date info", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</div>';
    }
    if( $value = $product->get_meta( '_time' ) ) {
        echo '<div class="vp-ccode-wrapper"><strong>' . __("Time info", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</div>';
    }
}

// Frontend: Display PP Info on product variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'vp_variation_display_pp_info', 10, 3 );
function vp_variation_display_pp_info( $data, $product, $variation ) {

    if( $value = $variation->get_meta( '_venue' ) ) {
        $data['price_html'] .= '<p class="vp-ccode"><small><strong>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
        ': </strong>'.esc_html( $value ).'</small></p>';
    }

    return $data;
}

// Frontend: Display info on cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'vp_cart_display_pp_info', 10, 3 );
function vp_cart_display_pp_info( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( ! is_cart() )
        return $item_name;

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><small class="vp-ccode"><strong>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
            ':</strong> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</small>';
    }

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><small class="vp-ccode"><strong>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
            ':</strong> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</small>';
    }

     if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><small class="vp-ccode"><strong>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
            ':</strong> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</small>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}



// Frontend: Display info on checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'vp_checkout_display_pp_info', 10, 3 );
function vp_checkout_display_pp_info( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<br><small class="vp-ccode"><strong>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") .
            ':</strong> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</small>';
    }

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<br><small class="vp-ccode"><strong>' . __("Date", "woocommerce") .
            ':</strong> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</small>';
    }

    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<br><small class="vp-ccode"><strong>' . __("Time", "woocommerce") .
            ':</strong> ' . esc_html( $value ) . '</small>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}




// Save PP Info to order items (and display it on admin orders)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'vp_order_item_save_pp_info', 10, 4 );
function vp_order_item_save_pp_info( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $order ) {
    if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_venue', esc_attr( $value ) );
    }

     if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_date') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_date', esc_attr( $value ) );
    }

      if( $value = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_time') ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_time', esc_attr( $value ) );
    }

    return $item_qty;
}

// Frontend & emails: Display PP Info on orders
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'vp_order_item_display_pp_info', 10, 4 );
function vp_order_item_display_pp_info( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    // Not on admin
    //if( is_admin() ) return;

    if( $value = $item->get_meta('_venue') ) {
        $value = '<strong>' . __("Venue", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . esc_attr( $value );

        // On orders
        if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
            echo '<div class="vp-ccode"><small>' . $value . '</small></div>';
        // On Emails
        else
            echo '<div style="font-size:11px;padding-top:6px">' . $value . '</div>';
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the hooks you use to declare your custom fields. Note the hooks are not the same for the main product and for product variations.

To add custom fields to variations I use this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', function( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'label'       => 'Vendor ID',
            'id'          => '_vendor_id[' . $variation->ID . ']',
            'value'       =>  get_post_meta( $variation->ID, META_PREFIX . 'vendor-product-id', true ),
        )
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'label'       => 'Updated on',
            'id'          => '_updated_on[' . $variation->ID . ']',
            'value'       =>  get_post_meta( $variation->ID, META_PREFIX . 'last-update', true ),
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}, 10, 3 );
```

To display the field, retrieve with a simple `get_post_meta()`

```
get_post_meta( $variation->ID, META_PREFIX . 'vendor-product-id', true );
```